# XSL match id with specific value and get child text

Tags: xml

I have an SVG that uses some namespace-specific attributes. I need to get the value of an ID that has a specific value, so that I can use it as a parameter.

Here is a snippet of the SVG of the info I need to get:

```
<g id="_166" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.0005" ntc:id="TITLE">
<g stroke="none" font-family="Arial">
  <text font-size="1.365" x="3.85222972" y="-0.04367862">Figure 2-33 TITLE OF FIGURE (Sheet 1 of 3) Change 15</text>
</g>
```

When I do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="getTitle" select="//@ntc:id = 'TITLE'"/>
```

It just returns true. I need to get the text inside of the svg:text descendant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression like

```
//*[@ntc:id = 'TITLE']//svg:text
```

(Assuming the `svg` prefix is bound to the appropriate namespace in your stylesheet). This will give you the set of `text` elements contained inside the element whose `ntc:id` is TITLE.

If all you care about is the text content rather than the `svg:text` element(s) themselves then it may be sufficient to do

```
<xsl:value-of select="//*[@ntc:id = 'TITLE']"/>
```

Since the string value of an element (in this case the g) is defined as the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.